# How can I get a list of default documents in IIS using PowerShell?

Tags: iis, powershell, windows-server-core

I'm managing a Server Core machine and trying to do everything in PowerShell, which is fun.  I need a list of the default documents.  From other websites, I've found out how to set and remove them, using both xxx-WebConfiguration and xxx-WebConfigurationProperty.  I've tried:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/defaultDocument -PSPath "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site" -Name files
```

but it gives:

```
Collection     : {Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement, Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.Configuration
                 Element, Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement, Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.Confi
                 gurationElement...}
ItemXPath      : /system.webServer/defaultDocument
Attributes     : {}
ChildElements  : {}
ElementTagName : files
Methods        :
Schema         : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

which doesn't really help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual document names are deeper in the hierarchy.  Here's how you can get a list of default docs:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/defaultDocument/files/add -PSPath "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site" -Name value | Select value
```